# If $T$ is a continuous bijection on $\mathbb R^d$, and $M$ is a $C^1$-submanifold with boundary, is $T(\partial M)=\partial T(M)$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $T:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ be bijective and continuous. I'm not sure how to approach this, but if $M\subseteq\mathbb R^d$, does $T$ map the topological boundary/interior of $M$ onto the topological boundary/interior of $N:=T(M)$? And if $M$ is an embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary, does $T$ map the manifold boundary/interior to the manifold boundary/interior of $N$? Or do we need further assumptions?

Comment: A continuous bijection on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism. And homeomorphism preserve topological boundaries and interiors.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Comment: Remark: There's a little more to be said here, since these are not the interior and boundary of $M$ within $\Bbb{R}^d$ but as a submanifold. But it's still defined only by means of the topology inherited from $\Bbb{R}^d$, so it's true.

Comment: @Cronus I'm not sure if I understand your comment correctly. The first two comments are related to the topology boundary/interior. Are you saying that it holds for the manifold boundary/interior as well? How do we show that?

Comment: What I am saying is that $\partial M$, when $M$ is a manifold, usually does not mean the boundary of $M$ as a subset of $\Bbb{R}^d$, but its boundary as a manifold. For instance, if $M=[0,1]\times \{0\}$, then the boundary of $M$ as a subset of the plane is all of $M$, but its boundary as a (sub)manifold is $\{0,1\}\times\{0\}$.

Comment: @Cronus Yes, I know. But is the claim in the question true for the manifold boundary/interior?

Comment: Yes, it is: a point is a boundary point of the manifold iff, in the induced subspace topology, it has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to $[0,1)$. It is an interior point iff, in the induced topology, it has a neighbourhood homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}$. Both things depend only on the topology of $M$ induced from $\Bbb{R}^d$, so we're good.